# Cfform validation with ajax request after form has validated

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfform

I've got an issue with a ColdFusion form which as per direction from management must use CF's form validation.

We need to submit data via an ajax request after the form has validated as true, and I've Googled how to use cfform validation but haven't been able to find out how to wait until ColdFusion has done validating the form via its on JS.

Is there some kind of object I can pass into my jQuery function to see if it returns true so I can then process my additional ajax requests?

Comment: You have kinda run into one of the reasons you should go back to "management" and say "this is why it's a bad idea to rely on ColdFusion handling mark-up/JS requirements, because once one needs to do something Adobe didn't predict, it becomes more work than just not having used `<cfform>` in the first place. So... let's rethink that illadvised decision, eh?" And see what happens from there.

Comment: I wonder what their justification for `<cfform>` is. In this day an age, jQuery is much more capable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do exactly what you say you want to do, code like this should work.

```
<cfform action="abc.cfm"
method="post"
onsubmit="return someJSFunction(this)">
```

The function, someJSFunction() will run after your form validates.  However, you might be doing things the hard way.  Instead of doing ajax requests to submit data, it would probably be a lot easier to submit that data with ColdFusion code in the form action page, abc.cfm in this example.

Comment: this resolved the issue nicely, plain and simple, I forgot that the standard onSubmit() functions after CF form validation. thanks very much